# Circuit abbreviation: GND, MIN, TRANS, etc?

Tags: photodiode

I am originally a programmer, so I am not quite experienced in circuit symbol and abbreviation. I receive a custom made 2-in-1 Light photo diode receiver + Current-to-Voltage converter from my professor and I'll have to write microcontroller program to receive data from light. However, there's 6 pins, and I don't know what to plug into those 6 pins. There are some notes written: 4.5V, GND, OUT, MIN, DIFF, TRANS. I only know that I should plug in 4.5V supply, Ground, and Output. I have absolutely no idea about the other three abbreviation (MIN, DIFF, TRANS). Unfortunately, my professor isn't available during this week, so I am on my own. Can you help identify what are those pins for?

Diagram: https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/t1/q77/s720x720/1925344_10152043333083095_442508481_n.jpg

Actual Circuit: https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/p296x100/1977361_10152043333208095_1265265624_n.jpg

Comment: It may be helpful to post a link to the notes or the part number. Context can be a wonderful thing.

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of inexperience in electronics, so can you give me an example of notes or part number? I have the circuit diagram at hand but not in digital form.

Comment: In any self-respecting schematic, where the component is, there should be a reference next to or near the part in question. This may include a unique identifier for the part in that circuit and should also mention the component number. For example, an MCU may have IC2 as a unique identifier (the 2nd IC chip on the board) and PIC18F2680 (the part number of a micro made by Microhip).

Comment: I post an actual image of the diagram, I hope this help

Comment: You might need to have a go at drawing the actual schematic, it's really hard to follow in that format especially for a double-sided board and some of the part numbers aren't visible.

Comment: There's the schematic, but stackexchange only allow me to post 2 links per topic, so I'll post it here: https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/t1/p296x100/1959293_10152043333338095_1731235290_n.jpg

Comment: @user38285, that looks a bit better but I can't see where those connections are. Maybe you could draw them on and take a clearer photo and use it to replace the existing links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice guide for abbreviations used in electronics you can find [here](http://www.altium.com/files/libraries/ls0001_pinabbreviation.pdf)

Includes some of the appendix A of ANSI/IEEE Std. 991-1986 which is the standard